# Any way to change the size mode directly in plotlyexpress

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have a plotly bubble chart where I am unsure of whether it is using the diameter or area to indicate the bubble size. A brief google told me that the default seems to be the diameter and I've been told that humans tend to perceive size through area? (Correct me if I'm wrong but this is just what I have been told through lectures.) Thus, I am trying to figure out a way to change the sizemode to area however can't seem to do that in plotly express. This is my code at the moment for reference.

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(data_frame = df, x="hf_score", y="Happiness.Score",
             size="GNI_capita", color="region", hover_name="countries", size_max=60,
             labels={
                 "hf_score" : "Human Freedom Index 2017 (0-10)",
                 "Happiness.Score" : "Happiness Score 2017 (0-10)",
                 "GNI_capita" : "GNI/capita 2017 by Atlas Method ($USD)",
                 "region" : "World Bank Region"
             },
             title="Happiness & Freedom Score by Region & GNI/capita")
```

EDIT:

Dataset Used: https://github.com/mattshu0410/data-1002-project/blob/master/merged_data.csv

Image Created: [image: Current Graph]

Comment: There certainly doesn't seem to be any change in the size mode on poorly.express If so, how about converting from diameter to area as size=x/2*x/2*pi. plotly.go might be able to use sizemode='area', so try it.[this page](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#scatter)

Comment: I just added the following code but it didn't seem to make a difference. Any idea why?`fig.update(data=dict(
    marker = [go.scatter.Marker(sizemode="diameter")]
))`

Comment: The documentation says you need a numerical array, so I guess you need a list of areas.

Comment: To be honest I am an absolute beginner and I am struggling to see how I could have a continuous data like GNI/capita and plot the bubble size based on area. If I pass a numerical array, won't I be forced to bin my GNI?

Comment: Providing sample data or graphs created at this time will make it easier to get responses from more people.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I have updated the question with my cleaned dataset and my current graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph the updated data with `go.scatter`. If you don't use `sizeref=`, the bubble is shrunk by `sizeref=` to make it larger. I can't embellish everything because I don't have time, but I think I have a skeleton.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

size = df['GNI_capita'].tolist()
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(x=df["hf_score"],
                                 y=df["Happiness.Score"],
                                 mode='markers',
                                 marker=dict(color=size,
                                             size=size,
                                             sizemode='area',
                                             sizeref=2.*max(size)/(40.**2))
                                )])

fig.show()
```

[image]